# Identify Performance Test Scenarios

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, test-plan

I'm planning to execute performance test scenarios for education domain related application.
It ha some major functions as below
 - Create school, configure school setups
 - Create curriculum course plans and create and publish courses and qualifications
 - Timetabled teachers and students
 - Teacher Teach functionality
 - Student Learn Functionality

I did the load test for teacher teaching and student learn scenarios around 5000 user request. But I have no proper idea how to do the performance test. What are the test scenarios. Please Any one can share any performance test plan or guidance to perform the load test + performance test scenarios

Comment: how did you execute the load test? did you use JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well-behaved load test must represent real (or anticipated) application usage as close as possible so you need to either ask what are number of schools, number of teachers/students per school, number of classes, think about ["peak" times](https://testguild.com/performance-peak-load/) (for example the system unlikely to be actively used during nights or weekends but on Monday morning pretty much everyone will log in and start doing/checking something). It is better to reach out to stakeholders for [non-functional requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) clarification, the business owners should have a better vision on how their product will be used that anonymous people from the Internet

JMeter's [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) represents a logical (or business) independent group of users, for example you can have one Thread Group for teachers and another Thread Group for students. As their behavior and footprint are different they should be separated. Students in their turn can be split into sub-groups like technical or applied arts or whatever. You can check [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability/) article for more details.